# Problem in using resizebox to zoom table

Tags: tables

I have a table too wide. When using resizebox, The color of the table would be too light. How to zoom the table while keeping the normal color? Thanks.

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \Large
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \centering 
    \caption{} 
    \label{}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \smallskip
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l*{9}{d{-2}} @{}} 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Regressions using Participation Rate}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){1-10} 
    &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Full Sample} 
    &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Group 1} 
    &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Group 2} 
    \\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} 
    & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} 
    & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} \\ 
    \midrule
    |\textit{BSCor}| 
    & -0.297^{***} & -0.210^{***} & -0.116^{***}
    & -0.345^{***} & -0.267^{***} & 0.046
    & -0.230^{***} & -0.180^{***} & 0.046\\ 
      & (0.036) & (0.034) & (0.035)
      & (0.053) & (0.052) & (0.046)
      & (0.046) & (0.045) & (0.046) \\ 
    \textit{Cor} 
    & & 0.019 & 0.026 
    & & -0.026 & 0.003
    & & 0.043^{*} & 0.003\\ 
      & & (0.021) & (0.020) 
      & & (0.032) & (0.003)
      & & (0.026) & (0.003)\\ 
    \textit{ln(y)} 
    &  & 0.422^{***}  & 0.338^{***}
    &  & 0.442^{***} & 0.043^{**}
    &  & 0.253^{***} & 0.253^{**} \\ 
      &  & (0.018) & (0.019)
      &  & (0.029) & (0.019)
      &  & (0.023) & (0.019) \\  
     \textit{age/10} 
     &  &  & -0.011
     &  &  & -0.004
     &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
      &  &  & (0.068)
      &  &  & (0.008)
      &  &  & (0.008) \\ 
      $age^2/100$ 
      &  &  & 0.003
      &  &  & -0.004
      &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
       &  &  & (0.008)
       &  &  & (0.008)
       &  &  & (0.008) \\ 
     \textit{Marriage} 
     &  &  & -0.162^{***}
     &  &  & -0.004
     &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
      &  &  & (0.025)
      &  &  & (0.008)
      &  &  & (0.008) \\
      \textit{FWealth} 
      &  &  & 0.044^{***}
      &  &  & -0.004
      &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
       &  &  & (0.002)
       &  &  & (0.008)
       &  &  & (0.008) \\
     $Std(d\delta)$
     &  &  & 0.019
      &  &  & -0.004
      &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
       &  &  & (0.050)
       &  &  & (0.008)
       &  &  & (0.008) \\
    $Skew(d\delta)$
    &  &  & -0.017^{*}
    &  &  & -0.004
    &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
      &  &  & (0.010)
      &  &  & (0.008)
      &  &  & (0.008) \\
    $Kurt(d\delta)$
    &  &  & -0.007
    &  &  & -0.004
    &  &  & -0.004 \\ 
      &  &  & (0.006)
      &  &  & (0.008)
      &  &  & (0.008) \\
    \midrule
       F-test & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2661} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2122} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$7.6729^{***}$} \\
       AIC & \multicolumn{1}{c}{37{,}997.73} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38{,}099.51} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{33{,}477.07} \\
       N & \multicolumn{1}{c}{624} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{624} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{624} \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{$^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$}
    \end{tabular} }
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Why even scale when you have this much space between columns. Note in general it is not recommended to scale tables as it leads to inconsistent font sizes in your document. Often it is better to redesign your table.

Comment: never use resizebox on tables just use a smaller font such as \small and reduce inter column spacing

Comment: @daleif@David You are right. The column space is way too large and resizebox is a bad command in academic or formal articles. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated `BSCor` and `Cor` should probably be typeset upright for example using `\mathrm{....}`

Answer (score 1):

With use of `\small` font size and reduced separation between columns and anticipated that page layout is default layout defined in the `geometry` package, you can get the following result:

[image]

(red lines are borders of text area)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
        }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {4}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-format={(}1.3{**}}

    \centering
    \small
\begin{talltblr}[
    caption={title},
      label={tab:tblr},
note{} = {Standard errors in parentheses:\newline
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.}
               ]{colsep  = 4pt,
                 colspec = {@{} l*{9}{X[c,si]} @{}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries},
                 row{4-Z}= {rowsep=0pt},
                 row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
                }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=10]{l}   Panel A: Regressions using Participation Rate
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\\
    \midrule
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{Full Sample}}} 
        &   &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{Group 1}}} 
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{Group 2}}}    
                        &   &               \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}  
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
    \cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
    & {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}}
    & {{{(4)}}} & {{{(5)}}} & {{{(6)}}}
    & {{{(7)}}} & {{{(8)}}} & {{{(9)}}}     \\
    \midrule
\textbar BSCor \textbar
    & -0.297\TblrNote{***}  & -0.210\TblrNote{***}  & -0.116\TblrNote{***}
    & -0.345\TblrNote{***}  & -0.267\TblrNote{***}  &  0.046
    & -0.230\TblrNote{***}  & -0.180\TblrNote{***}  &  0.046    \\
    & (0.036)               & (0.034)               & (0.035)
    & (0.053)               & (0.052)               & (0.046)
    & (0.046)               & (0.045)               & (0.046)   \\
Cor &                       & 0.019                 & 0.026
    &                       & -0.026                & 0.003
    &                       & 0.043\TblrNote{*}     & 0.003     \\
    &                       & (0.021)               & (0.020)
    &                       & (0.032)               & (0.003)
    &                       & (0.026)               & (0.003)   \\
$\ln(y)$ 
    &                       & 0.422\TblrNote{***}   & 0.338\TblrNote{***}
    &                       & 0.442\TblrNote{***}   & 0.043\TblrNote{**}
    &                       & 0.253\TblrNote{***}   & 0.253\TblrNote{**} \\
    &                       & (0.018)               & (0.019)
    &                       & (0.029)               & (0.019)
    &                       & (0.023)               & (0.019)   \\
age/10
    &                       &                       & -0.011
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.068)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
age$^2/100$
    &                       &                       & 0.003
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
Marriage 
    &                       &                       & -0.162\TblrNote{***}
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.025)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
FWealth
    &                       &                       & 0.044\TblrNote{***}
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.002)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
Std$(d\delta)$
    &                       &                       & 0.019
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.050)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
Skew$(d\delta)$
    &                       &                       & -0.017\TblrNote{*}
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.010)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
Kurt$(d\delta)$
    &                       &                       & -0.007
    &                       &                       & -0.004
    &                       &                       & -0.004 \\
    &                       &                       & (0.006)
    &                       &                       & (0.008)
    &                       &                       & (0.008) \\
    \midrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
F-test 
    & {{{0.2661}}}         & {{{0.2122}}}           & {{{7.6729\TblrNote{***}}}}%   \\
AIC & {{{37997.73}}}       & {{{{38099.51}}}        & {{{33 477.07}}}           %   \\
N   & {{{624}}}}           & {{{{624}}}             & {{{624}}}                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```